# pexpect script is passing in locally but when we triggered from jenkins pipeline always waiting to get the expected pattern

Tags: python, pexpect

```
child = pexpect.spawn("telnet {} {}".format(ip, port))
child.logfile = sys.stdout.buffer
child.delaybeforesend = None
try:
child.expect([r"Escape character is '\^\]'",
r".*Connection refused\r\n"], timeout=30)
child.sendline("\n")
child.sendline("\n")
index = child.expect([r"Username: ", ".*?>", ".*?#"], timeout=30)
if index == 1:
time.sleep(2)
child.sendline("en")
child.expect("Password: ", timeout=10)
time.sleep(1)
child.sendline("password")
child.expect(#"), timeout=10)
time.sleep(2)
child.sendline("cmd")
child.expect(#"), timeout=10)
time.sleep(3)
child.sendline("cmd")
child.expect(#"), timeout=10)
time.sleep(4)
child.sendline("cmd")
child.expect(#"), timeout=10)
time.sleep(3)
child.sendline("cmd")
child.expect("#", timeout=10)
time.sleep(2)
child.sendline("cmd")
print("3rd block executed")
print("interface set to default)
time.sleep(10)
child.expect("#", timeout=10)
child.sendline("\n")
child.sendline("some cmd")
time.sleep(10)
sh_line = child.before.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
for line in sh_line:
print(line)
child.close()
```

locally it is working fine but in the pipeline seeing below

```
22:33:59 Trying 10.102.126.141...
22:33:59 Connected to 10.102.126.141.
22:33:59 Escape character is '^\]'.
22:33:59
22:33:59
22:33:59
22:33:59
22:33:59
22:33:59
22:33:59
22:33:59
```

these many newline i have not given in my code, expected patterns `[r"Username: ", ".*?\>", ".*?#"]` not at all displaying but in the local expected patterns are displaying correctly after hit the telnet, can some one please help to fix this pipeline problem

I have tried by given time and also by passing newline(why because if we hit enter atleast it should display expected pattern.

expected :

```
22:33:59 Trying 10.102.126.141...
22:33:59 Connected to 10.102.126.141.
22:33:59 Escape character is '^\]'.
```

after this it should display expected patterns.

Comment: How is ssh involved here? The expect script is running telnet.

Comment: Hey @Kenster,  new to the n/w stuff but as per my understanding from the pipeline we need ssh to run our command remotely so we are using. above issue am facing only on pipeline not on the local